# Mobile optimization: Make notification menu with position:absolute scrollable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, notifications

I recently bought [Moltran](http://moltran.coderthemes.com/green/index.html) which is fine but has a big disadvantage: The notification menu disappears on mobile devices, which is not suiteable for me. So I learned that that this can be done removing the *hidden-xs* class of the li notification element. This will turn `<li class="dropdown hidden-xs open">` to `<li class="dropdown open">`, which works fine.

Now I stretched the small menu on the full width of the screen If the user has a smaller device for better usability:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .nav > li.dropdown:not(.hidden-xs).open .dropdown-menu {
        width: 100vw;
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, until one thing: I'm not able to scroll in the menu. Using a modern 5" smartphone horizontal, 3 elements at the end are hidden. Instead the scrolling will affect the background caused by the absolute position.

A simple demonstration on the [online demo](http://moltran.coderthemes.com/green/index.html) to make it more clear: I only removed the class *hidden-xs* because otherwise the menu would not appear on small windows in the line `<li class="dropdown hidden-xs open">` as I said before.

When the window is very small, its not able to see the full notification menu and the user isn't able to scroll there:

[image]

As you can see, the scroll bar on the right is at the bottom, but you can't full see the notifications because the scroll bar doesn't affect this menu. I tried a few things, mainly switching to other position types because the absolute position seems to cause the issue. But nothing worked, seems like I'm in a blind end.

**So my question is: What changes are necessary to keep the functionality as it is, but provide a way to scroll in the notifications on smaller devices?**

Comment: can you put your code in fiddle ?@Lion

Answer (score 5):

Well. If I understand correctly you should set overflow to your navigation bar. And it should do the trick.

```
.topbar{
    height: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

EDIT: This will set height of your topbar to 100%. Because of this it will overlap all elements on the screen.

As an alternative you can add a separate class when notification button is clicked and style this element only in such case. For example:

```
.topbar.notification-open{
    height: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

And toggle class with jQuery:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.topbar').toggleClass('notification-open');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the notification panel scrollable:

```
.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  left: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 100;

  // Extra code required

  overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; /* lets it scroll lazy */
  max-height: 500px; //or whatever. Could be 90vh
}
```

This should work just fine.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Just give a fixed height to ur notification  area with media query on small device and set overflow-y:auto. Height should be in px only. For example let notification_area is your div class..

```
@media (max-width:600px){
.notification_area{
    overflow-y:auto;
    height:300px;
    }
}
```